# circle image created by objective-c code has always been clipped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I was researching how to make a circle image by code in objective-c these two days.  I found several way to do this, but no matter which way, the image created is not an exact circle, which is cut.  Please see following code and image:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, radius*2.0f, radius*2.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);     
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

[image]

If you look at the image carefully, you will find that the edge has been cut.

Finally I found if I change the code as following:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, radius*2.0f+4, radius*2.0f+4);
CGRect rectmin = CGRectMake(2.0f, 2.0f, radius*2, radius*2);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectmin);
UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

The result is much better, but I don't think it's a nice solution.  Does anybody know exactly what's the problem of my first code snippet?  Thanks in advance.

p.s. all the screenshots are captured from the simulator.

[image]

Comment: boy, I stared at those circles for a while. Different colors for circle and bg will help like black and white. Just a FYI

Comment: Have a look here: [iOS draw filled Circles][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038017/ios-draw-filled-circles